# How can I play chunks of a video coming through a HTML5 websocket?

Tags: html, video-streaming, base64, websocket, chunks

Let's say I have an ogg video. I can play it like that :

```
<video width="640" height="480">
<source src="myvideo.ogg" type=video/ogg>
</video>
```

Now if I managed to stream 1ko chunks base64 encoded of this video through an HTML5 websocket, how could I play the video ? I can't figure this out. I can decode the chunks if needed.

Thanks in advance,
Nolhian

Comment: Any new findings on this? I would be interested in an answer also...

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at at [this](http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/stream-a-webcam-using-javascript-nodejs-android-opera-mobile-web-sockets-and-html5/). The solution does pretty the same what you want!